# How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, combobox, html-table

I have a html form which has a select list box from which you can select multiple values because its multiple property is set to multiple. Consider form method is 'GET'. The html code for the form is as follows:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="display.php">
      <table width="300" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Multiple Selection </label>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><select name="select2" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
            <option value="11">eleven</option>
            <option value="12">twelve</option>
            <option value="13">thirette</option>
            <option value="14">fourteen</option>
            <option value="15">fifteen</option>
            <option value="16">sixteen</option>
            <option value="17">seventeen</option>
            <option value="18">eighteen</option>
            <option value="19">nineteen</option>
            <option value="20">twenty</option>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to display the selected values in select list box on display.php page. So how are the selected values accessed on display.php page using `$_GET[]` array.

Comment: Are you allowed to rename `select2`? Or does someone else control the form?

Answer (score 429, accepted):

If you want PHP to treat `$_GET['select2']` as an array of options just add square brackets to the name of the *select element* like this: `<select name="select2[]" multiple …`

Then you can acces the array in your PHP script

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

foreach ($_GET['select2'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

`$_GET` may be substituted by `$_POST` depending on the `<form method="…"` value.

Comment: for me it seems, that browser does not send the post/get-parameter if nothing was selected of the multiple-select. how can you force to have an empty array, instead?

Comment: I had to use $_POST['select2'] instead of $_GET['select2']

Comment: This is an old answer, but this is a misleading answer! (name="select2[]") is correct as @Coufu answered!

Comment: @emfi If you want the parameter to be sent there must be a value; you can add "selected" to the tag (ie `<option value="" selected></option>`) if you can tolerate having a default option in the list. You can also use CSS to make the default option invisible; however if someone selects a different option, then unselects everything.. you can wind up with no value being returned. So.. there's no clean solution using GET.

Comment: Adding [] works for me both on POST and GET, but the resulting URI (with GET) is just too awful (..multiselect.php?ms%5B%5D=1&ms%5B%5D=2)

Answer (score 200):

Change:

```
<select name="select2" ...
```

To:

```
<select name="select2[]" ...
```

Comment: In some cases, why might this still not work? I am not getting success with this.

Answer (score 45):

You can use this code to retrieve values from multiple select combo box

HTML:

```
<form action="c3.php" method="post">
  <select name="ary[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Option 1" >Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$values = $_POST['ary'];

foreach ($values as $a){
    echo $a;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 35):

Use the following program for select the multiple values from select box.

multi.php

```
<?php
print <<<_HTML_
<html>
        <body>
                <form method="post" action="value.php">
                        <select name="flower[ ]" multiple>
                                <option value="flower">FLOWER</option>
                                <option value="rose">ROSE</option>
                                <option value="lilly">LILLY</option>
                                <option value="jasmine">JASMINE</option>
                                <option value="lotus">LOTUS</option>
                                <option value="tulips">TULIPS</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value=Submit>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
_HTML_

?>
```

value.php

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['flower'] as $names)
{
        print "You are selected $names<br/>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="display.php">
  <table width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label>Multiple Selection </label>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><select name="select2[]" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
        <option value="11">eleven</option>
        <option value="12">twelve</option>
        <option value="13">thirette</option>
        <option value="14">fourteen</option>
        <option value="15">fifteen</option>
        <option value="16">sixteen</option>
        <option value="17">seventeen</option>
        <option value="18">eighteen</option>
        <option value="19">nineteen</option>
        <option value="20">twenty</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can iterate it directly like this

```
foreach ($_GET['select2'] as $value)
    echo $value."\n";
```

or you can do it like this

```
$selectvalue=$_GET['select2'];
foreach ($selectvalue as $value)
    echo $value."\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

This will display the selected values:

```
<?php

    if ($_POST) { 
        foreach($_POST['select2'] as $selected) {
            echo $selected."<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: This has multiple flaws: 1) the OP was using GET method; 2) it's lacking the most important step of appending square brackets to the form element name, like `name="select2[]"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
// CHANGE name="select2" TO name="select2[]" THEN
<?php
  $mySelection = $_GET['select2'];

  $nSelection = count($MySelection);

  for($i=0; $i < $nSelection; $i++)
   {
      $numberVal = $MySelection[$i];

        if ($numberVal == "11"){
         echo("Eleven"); 
         }
        else if ($numberVal == "12"){
         echo("Twelve"); 
         } 
         ...

         ...
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do like this too. It worked out for me.

```
<form action="ResultsDulith.php" id="intermediate" name="inputMachine[]" multiple="multiple" method="post">
    <select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration[]" multiple="multiple"> 
        <option value="1 WEEK" >Last 1 Week</option>
        <option value="2 WEEK" >Last 2 Week </option>
        <option value="3 WEEK" >Last 3 Week</option>
         <option value="4 WEEK" >Last 4 Week</option>
          <option value="5 WEEK" >Last 5 Week</option>
           <option value="6 WEEK" >Last 6 Week</option>
    </select>
     <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Then take the multiple selection from following **PHP** code below. It print the selected multiple values accordingly.

```
$shift=$_POST['selectDuration'];

print_r($shift);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem with javascript + HTML. First i check selected options and save its in a hidden field of my form:

```
for(i=0; i < form.select.options.length; i++)
   if (form.select.options[i].selected)
    form.hidden.value += form.select.options[i].value;
```

Next, i get by post that field and get all the string ;-)
I hope it'll be work for somebody more. Thanks to all.

Comment: This has multiple flaws: 1) is depending on the JavaScript being available; 2) does not separate the values when joining them into a single string, thus making it imposible to split the string back into values later on.

Comment: This answer gives me the necessary direction. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST["select2"] as $selectedOption)
{    
    echo $selectedOption."\n";  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

form submit with enctype="multipart/form-data"