# Foreach multiple select outputs

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I have a form which has a multiple option selector in it:

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
</td>
<td>
   <select id="loyaltyType" required="required" name="VX_TYPE[]">
      <option>Choose Type</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
   </select>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="VX_NAME[]">
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="VX_EMAIL[]">
</td>
<td>
   <select name="VX_LOCATION[]" multiple>
      <option value="London">London</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

I would like the form to print with the following input/output:

**Input:**

B, sample name, sample email, New York + Toyko selected

D, sample name2, sample email2, London + Toyko selected

**Output:**

B, sample name, sample email, New York, Tokyo.

D, sample name2, sample email2, London, Tokyo.

However the actual output I am getting is as follows:

**Actual output:**

B, sample name, sample email, New York.

D, sample name2, sample email2, Tokyo.

This is the code for the output so far that does not work:

```
<?php foreach($VX_TYPE as $a => $b){ ?>
<p>
   <?php echo $VX_TYPE[$a]; ?>, <?php echo $VX_NAME[$a]; ?>, <?php echo $VX_EMAIL[$a]; ?>, <?php echo $VX_LOCATION[$a]; ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Any suggestions of how to get this working would be great!

Comment: what is `$VX_TYPE`?

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019947/handling-data-from-multiple-select-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you get the following in your post:

```
 array (
       VX_NAME  =>(
               [1] = sample1
               [2] = sample2
       )
       VX_TYPE => (
               [1] = B
               [2] = D
       )
       VX_LOCATION => (
               [1] = London
               [2] = Tokyo
               [3] = New York
     )
  )
```

your VX_LOCATION and VX_TYPE selections are going to be put into one array with no association to the NAME,EMAIL.  The form gives the user to add additional rows.  you will need to associate them to the location/type.

for example:

```
     array (
       VX_NAME  =>(
               [1] = sample1
               [2] = sample2
       )
       VX_TYPE => (
               [1] = B
               [2] = D
       )
       VX_LOCATION[1] => (
               [1] = New York
               [2] = Tokyo
       )
       VX_LOCATION[2] (
               [1] = London
               [2] = Tokyo
       )
  )
```

then you can do:

```
 foreach ($_POST['VX_NAME'] as $k => $v){
  echo $_POST['VX_TYPE'][$k] . "," . $v. ",". $_POST['VX_EMAIL'].",";
    foreach ($_POST['VX_LOCATION'][$k] as $kk => $vv){
       echo $vv . ",";
    }
 echo "<br>";
 }
```

Comment: the form I am pulling from gives the user options to add more identical input rows so the output comes out as an array

Comment: ok that make sense. I just edited my answer as you commented. does my edit do it for you?

Comment: I presume you meant: foreach ($_POST['VX_LOCATION'] as $k => $v){  ?

Comment: Yes, well you are going to have to loop through both if you want all the selected.  but yes, in this example $_POST['VX_LOCATION']

Comment: this didn't work, the output came up as  Array,Array,NewYorkParisNewYorkLondon (as in all the selected options from two inputs printed as one output)

Comment: that gives me: sample name, sample email, sample name2, sample email2, NewYorkParisNewYorkLondon

Comment: still no luck. This gives me: sample name, sample email, New York,Paris,NewYork,London, sample name2, sample email2, New York,Paris,NewYork,London

Comment: this gives the same thing

Comment: what is this result missing?

Comment: It gives the same list of locations in each instance @bart2puck

Comment: what are the key values for VX_NAME and VX_EMAIL?  check my update in a minute.