# How to get all values of multiple select box through POST?

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

I need to get all(Selected and unselected) the values of a multiple select box through POST. How can I do the trick?

Comment: show the code, have a  look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Answer (score 3):

Create a select tag like this

```
<select name="data[]" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

You can get the *selected* values:

```
foreach ($_GET['data'] as $selected) {
    echo $selected."\n";
}
```

You can not get the unselected values.

Comment: I have done the trick with some Javascript magic and now able to get all the values including selected and unselected.

Comment: The scenario was that I need to have two select box user selects the value from first box and it will go to the second box. that's why i needed to select all the values of second box

Comment: The above code wouldn't work. You are passing each element as `$selected` but printing `$selectedOption`