# Insert multiple choices in table of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, arrays

I have a `<select multiple="multiple">` to get multiple choices in php. After that I put it in a variable with the `POST` method and the I try to at least echo the array out to ensure that my variable`$authors` has the choices but it prints this error

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\addBook.php on line 45`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include ("includes/connections.php");
    $authors = $_POST["authors"];
    foreach ($authors as $author) 
    {
        echo $author;
    }
?>
```

here is the 'select multiple' I have in html :

```
<?php multiple("author_ID", "author_firstname", "author_lastname", "author", "author_lastname", "authors"); ?> <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #666;">(Keep down Ctrl for selecting multiple authors)</span>
```

here is the multiple function:

```
<?php include ("includes/connections.php");
    function multiple($intIdField, $strfNameField, $strlNameField, $strTableName, $strOrderField, $strNameOrdinal, $strMethod="asc") {
       echo "<select multiple=\"multiple\" name=\"$strNameOrdinal\">\n";

       $strQuery = "select $intIdField, $strfNameField, $strlNameField
                   from $strTableName
                   order by $strOrderField $strMethod";

       $rsrcResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

       while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) {
          $strA = $arrayRow["$intIdField"];
          $strB = $arrayRow["$strlNameField"] . " " . $arrayRow["$strfNameField"];    
          echo "<option value=\"$strA \">$strB</option>\n";
       }

       echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

So I would guess that the `$authors` variable would be an array and I would happily at least print, but as I already said this does not happen.

The Authors that are taken from the database are showing up correctly without any problem. the thing is I want the ones that are chosen from the 'select multiple' list to be echoed out.

Comment: The `$authors` array isn't being populated for some reason. You really should check against this condition to keep from getting that error.

Comment: how do I populate the '$authors' as an array from a '<select multiples = "multiples"' . That could be my main issue. Do i have to write something special in the select multiples?

Comment: Try the answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: I am trying several times but it is not working..maybe I'm declaring the variables in my function wrong or something, I just have no idea

Comment: Can you modify this part of the `multiple()` function? `name=\"$strNameOrdinal\">` If so, make it `name=\"$strNameOrdinal[]\">`

Comment: It says 'Notice: Undefined index: authors in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\addBook.php on line 44'

Comment: Obviously, `$strNameOrdinal` doesn't equal `authors` and the array PHP receives has a different index in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to attacks. See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel noted.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your multiple select in HTML needs to end in '[]' to denote that it is an array, then when you run your foreach loop in php, make sure that it is receiving an array, so it needs to either be set, or you need to typecast a single value as an array. I'm pretty sure your problem is in how you have the name attribute set though.