# How to pass multiple values of a variable through a URL

Tags: php, url, urlvariables

I've an application that I'm building, and I'm stuck at a certain point.

I'm trying to pass a variable that has multiple values. So my URL will look like:

```
localhost/report.php?variable=value1, value2, value3
```

Problem is I'm not sure how I can do this. The variables are to be used to retrieve data from a database. I'm using PHP and no Javascript.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML I have in my page where the variables are selected:

```
<select name="types" size="19" multiple>
    <option value="all" selected>All Types</option>
    <option value="book" selected>Books</option>
    <option value="cd" selected>CD</option>
</select>
```

So a user could select Books and CD, and I would need to pass these two values in the "types" variable.

Comment: how about a serialised array?

Comment: Are you using a from to send this? if so php should just get it as an array in $_POST['types']?

Comment: @wgcrouch I am using a form to send it. But when I do send it the URL ends up like `report.php?variable=value1&variable=value2`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: you need to change the name of your select element to types[]

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby I used the method in that link you posted and it worked. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407401/1265817, you can use this method.

If you want PHP to treat $_GET['select2'] as an array of options just add square brackets to the name of the select element like this: `<select name="select2[]" multiple …`

Then you can acces the array in your PHP script

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

foreach ($_GET['select2'] as $selectedOption)
  echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `&`

```
localhost/report.php?variable=value1&val2=value2&val3=value3
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: that's multiple variables, not one variable with multiple values

Comment: Sort of, what I really need is to add all of the values to that variable. So in the PHP code I can just use `$variable = $_GET['variable']`, so then I can use $variable in the query.

Comment: If both pages are on the same domain, you can use the `Session` variables? `Session["myStringName"] = someObject` then simply read it back by casting to what you need. Sorry, but my PHP isn't so good, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple way to do this in PHP by calling [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and pass your values as an indexed array. You would do something like:

```
$value_array = array('types' => array('book', 'cd'));
$query = http_build_query($value_array);
```

Then generate the url using `$query`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have your URL correct

```
localhost/report.php?variable=value1,value2,value3
```

Then use PHP to get all of the values on the report.php page

```
$variable = explode(",", $_GET["variable"]);

// Output
$variable[0] = "value1";
$variable[1] = "value2";
$variable[2] = "value3";
```

Answer (score 2):

try `localhost/report.php?variable[]=value1&variable[]=value2` will give you an array in php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) like:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?var='.serialize($array).'"> Link </a>';
```

and get data using [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) like:

```
$array= unserialize($_GET['var']);
```

serialize function giving you storable (string) version of array type, and can be restored by unserialize function.

Comment: Interesting idea. If I were to bookmark or copy a `index.php?var='.serialize($array).'` link, would I be able to reload that later or is the serialized data lost in the session?