# avoid php post variables rewriting

Tags: php

Is it possible to get an output like this using only 1 input?

```
<input name="value"/>
$_POST['value'] = 1;
$_POST['value'] = 2;
$_POST['value'] = 3;
$_POST['value'] = etc;
```

EDIT: I'm trying to pass an array using a single form input.

Comment: You mean having multiple input with same name and be able to read all results in PHP ? You are not very clear.

Comment: please rephrase your question - it's not obvious what you need/want.

Comment: maybe `name="value[]"` but im as clear as everyone else on what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you're trying to pass an array using a single form `input` the short answer is no, using a single element you cannot pass an array into the POST array (with the exception of the [multi-select form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)), but it's easy with a *tiny* bit of processing once you submit. You just use a delimiter on the value and explode it in PHP:

In HTML:

```
<input name="value" value="1|2|4|4|5" />
```

In PHP

```
$values = explode('|',$_POST['value']);
```

This will result in:

```
$values[0] == 1;
$values[1] == 2;
...
```

However, **there is never a way to get a PHP array to have multiple values for a single key** at the same time, so you can never have a PHP array that looks like:

```
$_POST['value'] = 1;
$_POST['value'] = 2;
$_POST['value'] = 3;
$_POST['value'] = etc;
```

Because for any array (`_POST` or otherwise) $array[KEY] can not have two values (i.e. how can `if ($_POST['value'] === $_POST['value'])` ever not be true? It can't, any more that `if ($x===$x)` or `if (1===1)` can be false). You can, however, use a multi-dimensional array, which would look like:

```
$_POST['value'][0] = 1;
$_POST['value'][1] = 2;
$_POST['value'][2] = 3;
$_POST['value'][3] = 'etc';
```

and then work with it by:

```
foreach($_POST['value'] as $key =>$value){
    echo $value.',';
}
```

which would output

```
1,2,3,etc
```

Comment: you should add info about array notation in html field names. :)

Comment: i *think* that the OP was interested in a single input -> multiple outputs rather than just how to pass an array into the _POST array. Though the question isn't exactly clear

Answer (score 1):

To submit multiple input with same name, append brackets `[]` at the end like this

```
<input type="text" name="bob[]" />
<input type="text" name="bob[]" />
<input type="text" name="bob[]" />
<input type="text" name="bob[]" />
<input type="text" name="bob[]" />
```

On the other side, `bob` will be an array :

```
<?php

$Bob = (isset($_POST['bob']) === TRUE ? $_POST['bob'] array());

echo 'RES:'. implode(',', $Bob);

?>
```

Comment: +1 I believe that was exactly what the OP meant, even though it was poorly phrased. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but it's not exactly what I wanted, sorry for my poor phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you store the values one at a time, using ajax perhaps.