# Sending HTML Form Multiple <select> box via POST request with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, arrays, forms

I have an html form with a multiple select box. I can't figure out how to send the values to my php application with AJAX via a post request.  It works just fine if I use a GET request and use a single select box but not when I use a multiple select box. The idea is for users to hold control (or command with mac) and select one or more categories. Depending on which categories are selected will determine what other form options will be displayed using AJAX. The select box looks like this:

**Edit: SOLVED**

```
<select multiple name="categories[]" onclick="sendCategories(this)">
<option value="0">Category 1</option>
<option value="1">Category 2</option>
<option value="2">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

My javascript function looks like this:

```
function sendCategories(sel){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.mysite.com/update_categories.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var values = $(sel).serialize();
    xmlhttp.send(values);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to generate the query string to send in the POST on your own. Here's the HTML tag to use:

```
<select multiple name="categories[]" onchange="sendCategories(this);">
```

And the Javascript function:

```
function sendCategories(sel){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.mysite.com/update_categories.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var values = [], i, j, cur;
    for (i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = sel.options[i];
        if (cur.selected) {
            values.push(encodeURIComponent(cur.value));
        }
    }
    if (values.length) {
        values = encodeURIComponent(sel.name) + "=" + values.join("&" + encodeURIComponent(sel.name) + "=");
    } else {
        values = null;
    }

    xmlhttp.send(values);
}
```

Note that I changed the event from `onclick` to `onchange`, but that's really up to you whether you want this function to run when the element is clicked, or its value is truly changed...it can reduce some unnecessary calls.

This should generate a querystring that is normally used for sending values for a `<select>` with multiple options selected.

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates how the querystring is being generated here: http://jsfiddle.net/kKWQM/

Comment: Hmmm.... definitely getting warmer. Seems like this would work but for some reason when I try to retrieve the post request on the server end with my php application, I'm still not getting anything. I'm trying to to check the values like this:    print_r($_POST['values'])

Comment: @kyzer1978 Awesome, glad you're getting closer! So, I'm not sure why you're using `$_POST['values']` - if you look at the `alert` in the jsFiddle, you'll notice the querystring is something like: `categories[]=asdf&categories[]=fdsa&categories[]=aaa`. So the "key" that should be used is "categories[]" when accessing `$_POST`. That means, you should try `$_POST['categories[]']`. Does that make sense? Try that out and let me know what happens. If that doesn't work, try `$_POST['categories']`. `values` is just the name of the Javascript variable and has no relation to what's sent to the server

Comment: @kyzer1978 The reason it "has no relation to what's sent to the server" is because I am emulating what is done when a multiple `<select>` is normally submitted (without AJAX). When forms are submitted, each input's value is submitted as `key=value`, where the `key` is the `name` attribute of the element, and the `value` is the current value of the element. With a multiple `<select>`, there needs to be a way to distinguish between all values selected. So while normally, it would be `categories[]=val1` for a non-multiple `<select>`, it replicates that for every value selected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Makes total sense now to use  $_POST['categories']. Unfortunately though it doesn't seem to be working yet with or without the extra brackets. I did notice in the jsFiddle you sent that when I changed the values in the select box I still got the same query string.

Comment: @kyzer1978 Hmm that's weird. When I run the fiddle, I get all values selected. So say you click on the first option - it alerts `key=value`. Then hold control and click another - it should alert `key=value&key=value2`. It does for me at least. Here's a fiddle that alerts something less jumbled: http://jsfiddle.net/svYwL/1/

Comment: @kyzer1978 I'm not the most fluent in PHP, but according to this post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php ), it says in order to access the values on the server, the name should be "categories[]" (with the []), and then access it like `$_POST["categories"]` (without the []). I would think since you use `print_r`, it would work just fine.

Comment: Yep, you're right. You're function is working like it's supposed to but for some reason the server isn't reading it correctly.  I can clearly see the data being sent the way it's supposed to when I check it in firebug. It looks like this: categories%5B%5D%3D0%26categories%5B%5D%3D1%26categories%5B%5D%3D2%26 when I click all three.  That looks just like it should using percent encoding.  I even tried removing the encodeURIComponent function and got this: categories[]=0&categories[]=1&categories[]=2  Weird. Got to be something on my server end that I am not doing right.

Comment: @kyzer1978 Right, the `encodeURIComponent` is just useful for the "correct" encoding for transmitting data through HTTP. Is there any other important PHP code you have, that you could include in your original question? Also, would you be able to debug the PHP and see what the full contents of `$_POST` are? I don't know what PHP code would do this, but some way of seeing what is all in `$_POST`?

Comment: There's something going on with the encryption.  The best solution seemed to be Jquery and then setting the appropriate request header: setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); I really wish I could figure out why just using javascript didn't work but if Jquery works then I'll just go that route.

Comment: @kyzer1978 Hey, whatever works for you! jQuery really shouldn't be required for this. I'm not sure what jQuery you ended up using, but using `.serialize()` does the same thing as I posted for generating the querystring. I should've recognized the need for the request header, I forgot about that with POST

Comment: @kyzer1978 Ahh I see what `.serialize` is doing differently. It doesn't seem to be encoding `=` and `&`. So I updated my answer to only encode the `key` and `value` in the pairs and that's it. Yet another dumb mistake by me. Hopefully that would fix it. I could've sworn it was okay to just call `encodeURIComponent` on the final querystring you were going to pass.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this,

```
<select multiple name="categories[]" onclick="sendCategories(this)">
```

And Make AJAX using JQuery,

```
function sendCategories(sel){
    var values = $(select).serialize();
    console.log (values);       // See if you get the serialized data in console.

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://www.mysite.com/update_categories.php"
        data: values,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

And FYI, Netscape event binding model is deprecated, you could use the cross browser event binding like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it didn't work. Is there another step I have to do on the server end once the values are sent? For instance, do I have to unserialize the values first before it will work?

Comment: I tried both print_r($_POST['values']);   and also  print_r(unserialize($_POST['values'])); but I didn't get anything.

Comment: @kyzer1978 See if you get the values in `console.log(values)`, if yes, then you should see how you are sending the values to the server. Try the edited code..

Comment: Jquery did the trick!  I did have to set the RequestHeader first though.  I added xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); to my original code and used the serialize() function and boom!  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the solution however you would like using JS string and array functions. Effectively, the string you need to send to Apache should contain a pattern like:

`xxx[]=a&xxx[]=b&xxx[]=c`

where the SELECT element's name is `xxx[]` in your form and a, b, and c are three values the user selected.

So yes, you are repeating a key name as many times as the user selected a different option in the SELECT.

In JS you can use an array of selected options:

```
selected_options.join("&xxx[]=") to produce that pattern.
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should make this easier for you.  Calling .val() on a wrapped select returns an array of the selected values.  You just have to post these to the server:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="mySelect" multiple="on">
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
                <option value="3">Tres</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Click To Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitButton').click(function() {
        var valuesArray = $('select[name=mySelect]').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/path/to/php', // your php url would go here
            data: { mySelect: valuesArray }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            // parse response from msg
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: downvoter please comment what is wrong here. I do not see anything wrong in this.

Comment: Thanks but I am actually trying to generate dynamic html code before the entire form is submitted to the server so this doesn't solve the problem.  I basically want to reveal different options in the form whenever the user clicks on different categories in the select box before the form is sent to the server via AJAX.