# Ajax Post : Array of Object posted , not able to retrieve in php side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

> "company=1&cat=3&cat=1"

my Javascript object **"cat"** have two values 1,3 and

```
var cat = [];
cat.push(1);
cat.push(2);
```

now i want post it to servr using AJAX , I am able to post the data

and I can see data appearing in PHP side 
but my problem is

when I capture posted data in php it is only showing one value of **cat**

actual data = company=1 ,  cat= [1,3];

here is my posted query  = **company=1&cat=3**

this is what PHP print_r  showing =

```
 Array
(
    ["company] => 1
    [cat] => 3
    "
)
```

as you can see , the cat value is only one value instea of array (1,3)

what i am missing here ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[]` to pass an array. Your url should become like:

"company=1&cat[]=3&cat[]=1"

Then `$_GET['cat']` will return `array(3,1)`;

Comment: I just used $.param() to encode objects and it showing cat=1&cat=3 only .

Comment: What Daan is saying is, if you were to create html forms, with fields, you would need to set the names of these fields as "cat[]" in order for the posted result to be an array.

Comment: @relequestual I collection  Options of Select from Jquery then i am pushing that to object 'cat'   when I call  console.log(cat) i can see result as ['1',3']

Comment: OK, in which case, you need to re-name your from "cat" to "cat[]", using the name attribute. This is a related question with some code which you may find helpful if that doesn't solve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766103/sending-html-form-multiple-select-box-via-post-request-with-ajax