# How do I POST all options in a select list?

Tags: php, javascript, select

I have a select multiple list that has a few items in it.  It is a list of IP addresses for an ACL.  People can add/remove IPs, and then save the list. However, unless you select an item on the list, `$_POST[selectName]` does not contain any values. How can I accomplish this? I know I can do this with javascript but I would rather stick to PHP.

Comment: The browser doesn't send those values to PHP, you'll need Javascript to manipulate the submission process. Hence, there is no PHP only way  to do this

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: The traditional way to do this is use making the select multi-selectable, then on form submission have javascript select all options.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit/corrected: You need JS. There is no way to send all (selected and not selected) options via POST. You have to programatically select all options before submission.

File with form (file1.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAll() 
    { 
        selectBox = document.getElementById("someId");

        for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) 
        { 
             selectBox.options[i].selected = true; 
        } 
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="file2.php">
    <select id="someId" name="selectName[]" multiple>
        <option value="123.123.123.123">123.123.123.123</option>
        <option value="234.234.234.234">234.234.234.234</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=Submit onclick="selectAll();">
</form>
```

File that receives POST (file2.php):

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST['selectName'] as $item)
    {
    print "$item<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: He wants *all* the available values sent from a `multiple`, not just the selected ones.

Comment: @Pekka웃 aaah so maybe he should set all these options as selected?

Comment: yup; he'll need JavaScript for that

Comment: Can somebody confirm my new answer?

Comment: That looks okay, although it might be better to bind the selectAll() to the form's `submit` event (ie. `onsubmit`)

Answer (score 1):

Just to tack on this you could also use the jQuery version of @Kamil's code which is a little simpler than the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('[name="form1"]').on("submit",selectAll);

function selectAll() 
{ 
    jQuery('[name="selectName[]"] option').prop('selected', true);
}

</script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="file2.php">
<select id="someId" name="selectName[]" multiple>
    <option value="123.123.123.123">123.123.123.123</option>
    <option value="234.234.234.234">234.234.234.234</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=Submit onclick="selectAll();">  
</form>
```