# Javascript on submit from multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this code :

```
<div class="st-form-line">
        <span class="st-labeltext">Countries</span>
        <label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_0" name="members_create_campaign_form[countrySelectionType]" required="required" value="0" checked="checked" /> All</label>
        <label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1" name="members_create_campaign_form[countrySelectionType]" required="required" value="1"/> Selected</label>
        <div id="clist_div" class="simplebox cgrid540-right" style="display:none;">
            <div style="padding:5px"></div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Excluded Countries</b></p>
                <select size="10" name="excluded2" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['excluded2'],this.form['countries[]'])" multiple >
                                                                               <?php foreach($arrayCountries as $country) {?>
                                                <option value="<?= $country ?>" ><?= $country ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>

              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid40-left">
                <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="right" value="&gt;&gt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['excluded2'],this.form['countries[]'])"><br/><br/>
                <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="left" value="&lt;&lt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['countries[]'],this.form['excluded2'])">
            </div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Selected Countries</b></p>
                <select size="10" id="members_create_campaign_form_countries" name="countries[]" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['countries[]'],this.form['excluded2'])" multiple >
                                        </select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
```

This code look like this:
[image]

after i choose some countries from left side is adding me to right side, ok, that's good, but my problem is if is not selected as in this photo
[image]

is not adding in my database, and in this screnshoot it added only Canada and Germany that is selected and normally i want to add all countries that is added in right side.

This is js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1').is(':checked')) {
        $('#clist_div').show('slow');
    }
    $('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_0').click(function () {
        $('#clist_div').hide('slow');
    });
    $('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1').click(function () {
        $('#clist_div').show('slow');
    });

    function selectDiff(s1Id, s2Id) {
        var selected = $('#' + s2Id + ' option').map(function(){
            return this.value;
        }).get()

        var excluded = $('#' + s1Id + ' option').each(function() {
            if (selected.indexOf(this.value) != -1) {
                selected.splice(selected.indexOf(this.value), 1);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }).get()
    };

    selectDiff('clist_div', 'members_create_campaign_form_countries');
});
```

Comment: where do you submit the form?

Comment: The SELECT behaves as normal. You just created a second SELECT with the filtered data from the first one, but only the selected OPTIONs get submitted from a SELECT.

Comment: Is not about that, my form is working, is adding, but is adding only when in right side i select again like second screnshoot, is adding only that not all from right side, i think is something from js code

Comment: As @PeterRakmanyi said this IS the default behavior of a select element in HTML. Only the selected options are submitted not the whole list. You would have to: On-Submit select all items in 2nd select so all are sent.

Comment: how i can do On-Submit select all items in 2nd select ?

Comment: something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190464/how-do-i-post-all-options-in-a-select-list)

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** you need to `select  the all` option in `selected countries` `on submit`

**2nd :** simple add `selected attribute` in `all option` in `selected countries`

**Note :** consequently if your adding to `selected countries` and removing from `selected countries` means . option `loose the selected` `attribute` so you need to add the `selected attribute` on submit

```
$(document).on('submit','#submit_button',function(){

   $('#members_create_campaign_form_countries option').prop('selected',true);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the selected countries as array and keep pushing selected countries in to that.

For example:

```
var selected_countries=[];

//on select country

selected_countries.push('country selected');
```

use selected_countries array add to DB.