# getting javascript variables to PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Forgive me but i am new at this. I have a php script that generates a HTML select element which dynamically populates the options with contact information generated from a mySQL database. the contact information include the firstname,second name and phone number. I have created a second HTML select element which is empty to begin with.

two java script funnctions were created. the first is called addcontacts the job of this function is to remove the contacts from the first select element and add them into second select element. the second javascript functions, removeContacts, does it the other way round.

once all the desired contacts are added to the second select element, i would like only the phone numbers to be added to a php array. the idea is that an sms message is sent to the numbers selected.

this is my code,

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sender</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
function addContact()
{
    var cont = document.getElementById("contacts");
var snd = document.getElementById("send");
var opt = document.createElement("option");
for (var i=0; i <cont.options.length; i++)
{
    if(cont.options[i].selected == true)
    {
        var selOpt = cont.options[i];
        opt.value = selOpt.value;
        opt.text = selOpt.text;
        try
        {
            snd.add(opt,null);
            cont.remove(i,null);
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            snd.add(opt);
            cont.remove(i);
        }
        i--;
    }
}
//snd.options.add(opt);
//opt.text = name;
//opt.name = id;
}
function removeContact()
{
var cont = document.getElementById("send");
var snd = document.getElementById("contacts");
var opt = document.createElement("option");
for (var i=0; i <cont.options.length; i++)
{
    if(cont.options[i].selected == true)
    {
        var selOpt = cont.options[i];
        opt.value = selOpt.value;
        opt.text = selOpt.text;
        try
        {
            snd.add(opt,null);
            cont.remove(i,null);
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            snd.add(opt);
            cont.remove(i);
        }
        i--;
    }`enter code here`
}
}
  </script>
   <h2>Sender- Send Message</h2>
   <form method="post" action="send.php">
    <fieldset id="message">
<?php

echo 'Hello '. $_SESSION['username'].' <br/>';

?>
<br/>
<label for="firstname">Please enter your name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
<br/>

<label for="message">Please type your message</label>
<br/>

<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea><br />
<br/>
<br />

    <?php

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="contacts"; // Database name 
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

 $query = "SELECT contactID, firstName, secondName, phone_number FROM   phone_numbers                 WHERE userID = $userID ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $phone_numbers = array();
    echo "<select name='contacts' id='contacts'  multiple
            style='width:200px'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<option value=".$row['contactID']. ">".$row['firstName'].'   '.$row['secondName'].' - ' .$row['phone_number']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";






?>

<input type="button" onclick="addContact()"  value="Add"/>
<input type="button" onclick="removeContact()"  value="Remove"/>
<br/>
<select name="send" id="send"  multiple style="width:200px">
<input type="submit" value="Add Contact" name="addcontact" />


</select>
<br />
<br />

<label for="number"> Or type in a single number: </label>
<br/>
<input type= "text" id="number" name="number"/>
<br/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" />
<input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will be forgiven: http://php.net/tutorial.forms - Is there any programming question that has been left open? If so, please let us know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Comment: so it is not possible to achieve what i intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP executes on the server side. JavaScript executes on the client side. Before your page is displayed to the user, PHP has completed its job. You will need to either redirect, refresh, or make an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request, but the point is that you need to send the information back to the server somehow.

So, to answer your question...no, you cannot set a PHP variable from JavaScript.