# Trouble with retrieving data from mysql with HTML select box

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay so I am developing a search engine for a non-profit group using MYSQL and PHP.  The data appears fine from all the other fields.  But when I try to get data from a drop down select box the data doesn't appear.
  I know my code is pron to SQL injections however there isn't any important data kept on the server, it just info about treatments and research studies.

I would like to do it with a function.  I was also wondering if there is anyway to retrieve data from multiple boxes.  Like I have a keyword search and a drop down combo box both of them are set.  How do I retrieve data from both columns in the database using the function I have?  Thanks 
Here is my code if you guys could help me that would be great thanks
  The code for the html box

```
                          Broad Research Topic <select name="Treatment1">
                          <option value="Other">
                                    Other
                          </option>
                          <option value="Treatment">
                                    Treatment
                          </option>
                          <option value="PracticalCure">
                                    Practical Cure
                          </option>
```

The php code to check if it is set

```
               if (isset($_GET['Treatment1']) && in_array($_GET(['Treatment1']),       
               array('Treatment', 'PracticalCure', 'Other')) {


                $state =  $_GET['Treatment1']; 
                Investigator6($state); }
                 }
```

The Function Investigator6

```
       function Investigator6($state)
       {

       $state = trim($state);
       $state = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $state);

      //seperate multiple keywords into array space delimited
       $keywords = explode(" ", $state);

       //Clean empty arrays so they don't get every row as result
       $keywords = array_diff($keywords, array(
        ""
        ));

        //Set the MySQL query
        if ($state == NULL or $state == '%') {
         } else {
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i++) {
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM Studies1 WHERE BroadResearchTopic LIKE   
       ' %$keywords[$i]%'");
       }

       //Store the results in a variable or die if query fails
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       }
       if ($state == NULL or $state == '%') {
       } else {
       //Count the rows retrived
       $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
      echo $count;
      }

      //If search variable is null do nothing, else print it.
       if ($state == NULL) {
       } else {
       echo "You searched for <b><FONT COLOR=\"blue\">";
       foreach ($keywords as $value) {
        print "$value ";
       }
      echo "</font></b>";
       }
       echo "<p> </p><br />";
       echo "</center>";

     //If users doesn't enter anything into search box tell them to.
     if ($state == NULL) {
    echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please enter a search parameter to continue.                   
    b</font></b><br /></center>";
   } elseif ($state == '%') {
    echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please enter a search parameter to continue.  
    </font></b><br /></center>";
    //If no results are returned print it
    } elseif ($count <= 0) {
    echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Your query returned no results from the   
    database.</font></b><br /></center>";
    //ELSE print the data in a table
     } else {
    //Table header
     echo "<center>";
     echo "</center>";

    //Colors for alternation of row color on results table
    $color1 = "#d5d5d5";
    $color2 = "#e5e5e5";
    //While there are rows, print it.
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //Row color alternates for each row
        $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
        //table background color = row_color variable
       echo "<td style = \"padding: 10px\">" . $row['BroadResearchTopic'] . "</td>";
       $row_count++;
       if ($state == NULL or $state == '%') {
       } else {
      //clear memory
      mysql_free_result($result);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Its a typeo ill fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Comment: No it isn't. I tried that.  It was no help.  Mine is a little bit more complicated  I'm trouble with the function.

Comment: The $state value will always be one of these values: 'Treatment', 'PracticalCure', 'Other'. Is this the correct terms that you are querying on?

Comment: Why is your function splitting up a space-separated list of words? The form doesn't send that, it just sends the one keyword that you selected, and the validation code only allows one keyword.

Comment: Yes Jeff that is correct

Comment: Barmar why not offer some help.  It's obvious I'm a little bit new.

Comment: I just tried removing the keywords explode and array diff and the for loop still nothing

Comment: No ones going to help me?

Comment: If the $state value is one from the &lt;select&gt; control then there is no need to do all that extra processing i.e. explode, array_diff etc.