# php html javascript keep multiple values selected after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to keep the selected values after I submit the form. My code works fine when I select only one value. It does not keep all values, when I select multiple values all at once. Please help.

```
<select name="education" id="education" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor's
            <option value="Master">Master's
            <option value="PhD">PhD
</select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('education').value = "<?php echo $_POST['education'];?>";
        </script>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It does work with jQuery!:) You have to insert an array to the val():

```
     $('#education').val(['Bachelor', 'Master', 'PhD']);
```

Live example [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk8GX/2/)