# Options not showing "selected' after saving

Tags: php, html, wordpress, select

**Problems:**

The save works, but is only storing one of the options in the database after save.

Options not showing as selected after save.

The select fields:

```
<select id="exclude_page_from_cookies" name="exclude_page_from_cookies[]" multiple="multiple">
        <?php

        $pages = get_pages();
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $title = $page->post_title;
            $id    = $page->id;
            ?>

            <option id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $title ?>" <?php selected( $title ); ?> >
                <?php echo $title;?>
            </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

The save function:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] as $exclude_page ) {
         echo $exclude_page;
         update_option( 'exclude_page_from_cookies', $exclude_page ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: thanks but that doesn't have anything about update_option() or any save functions.

Comment: `$_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies']` will be an array if using `exclude_page_from_cookies[]`. Just loop over it and call `update_option()` every time (assuming `update_option()` does not overwrite previous values - consult the approriate documentation of the function.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `selected()` is a wordpress function?

I guess your line should look like this:

```
 <option <?php selected( $title ); ?> value="<?php echo $title ?>">
```

(with `selected` outside of `value=""`)

**EDIT**

as per @comfreak:

```
foreach($_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] as $exclude_page ){
 update_option('exclude_page_from_cookies',$exclude_page);
}
```