# How to insert multiple selectbox item in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a select box which have multiple item select facility

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" name="mul[]">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>

                        </select>
```

Here select box item generate dynamically from another table.so item amount can be increase or decrease.for this reason i cant use set data type.

Now i want to insert selected value in my database table.

MY table look like

```
id  name   item

1   first   mul[] value

2   second  mul[] value
```

I want to insert selected item in DB Table column named item.

Also i want to retrieve every row data.

view like

```
id  name   item

1   first   1,2,3

2   second  2,4
```

I tried

```
$select_value=$_POST['mul'];

$sql="insert into mytable (`id`, `name`, `item`) VALUES (null, 'Hallo',$select_value)";
```

Comment: sounds like a good goal, what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Use php impload function.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_implode

In your case it will b like

```
$select_value=implode(", ", $_POST['mul']);

$sql="insert into mytable (`id`, `name`, `item`) VALUES (null, 'Hallo',$select_value)";
```

Then insert it.. :)

Try this.. i hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically changes array to string, with comma:

```
$select_value = join($_POST['mul'],',');
```

Answer (score 0):

'implode' of php is the solution:

```
echo implode(",",$_POST['mul']);//here $_POST['mul'] = ['1','2','3']
```

It will output string "1,2,3", insert it your table.

Here is more info about implode [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Also ,if you want to retrieve records from DB table using your option values then FIND_IN_SET() function of sql will be useful , the query will be :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('option_value',`item`) <>0
```