# Trouble in getting multiple selected dropdown box values in php

Tags: php

My html code is like below

```
 <select multiple="multiple" size="2" name="exServer[]">
 <option value="1"> host.newcybage.alabanza.com </option>
 <option value="2"> host2.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="3"> host3.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="5"> host3.devel.php5.qa.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="7"> centos5host2.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="8"> centos5host.template.alabanza.com </option> 
 </select>

<input type="submit" value="Apply" name="exSubmit" class="button">
```

And my php code is like below

```
$arr=$_POST['exServer'];
print_r($_POST['exServer']);
print_r($arr);
```

Both print statements are giving me no results.
I dont know where i am wrong in getting selected multiple dropdown values.

I verified  using HttpFox that data is getting posted properly on server side.
When i am printing value of exSubmit, it is giving me proper values.

```
print "Exsubmit:".$_POST['exSubmit']; //Result Exsubmit:Apply
```

Please help.

Comment: of course, besides from the missing form tags, did you pick any one those options?

Comment: have you tried `$_POST['exServer[]']` ?

Comment: I have given form tag thats why i am getting correct values of exSubmit .Its just that i have not put it form tag here

Comment: No Form tag? hahaha! That's it.

Comment: I tried print_r($POST); I m getting below result Array ( [exDay] => 01 [exMonth] => 09 [exYear] => 2014 [exDay2] => 16 [exMonth2] => 09 [exYear2] => 2014 [exServer] => [exSubmit] => Apply ) I getting all  values except exServer

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2" name="exServer[]">
 <option value="1"> host.newcybage.alabanza.com </option>
 <option value="2"> host2.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="3"> host3.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="5"> host3.devel.php5.qa.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="7"> centos5host2.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="8"> centos5host.template.alabanza.com </option> 
 </select>
```

My suggestion is to print the array $_POST and see the values passed in the backend.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: nope dude, you need to set it as an array name if you want a multiple, `exServer[]`. [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0e630D)

Comment: No while getting multiple selected values from dropdown  we need put name as an array like i gave exServer[]

Comment: Then, explain Alexandre Jasmin's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: @kimbarcelona huh? that particular answer has this: `<select name="select2[]" multiple`

Comment: Yeah, miseen that thing. Then I suppose nothing is wrong. Can you try to print_r($POST); and see what the output is?

Comment: ya dude that is what i am saying. I want multiple values that is why i have put name as an array like exServer[]

Comment: I tried print_r($POST); I m getting below result Array ( [exDay] => 01 [exMonth] => 09 [exYear] => 2014 [exDay2] => 16 [exMonth2] => 09 [exYear2] => 2014 [exServer] => [exSubmit] => Apply ) I getting all values except exServer

Comment: which comes first the form tag or the php code? can you give us more code?

Answer (score 0):

you code is working. I tried this and got all the selected values in PHP

```
<?php
$arr=$_POST['exServer'];
print_r($_POST['exServer']);
print_r($arr);
?>

<form method="post">

    <select multiple="multiple" size="2" name="exServer[]">
 <option value="1"> host.newcybage.alabanza.com </option>
 <option value="2"> host2.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="3"> host3.newcybage.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="5"> host3.devel.php5.qa.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="7"> centos5host2.alabanza.com </option> 
 <option value="8"> centos5host.template.alabanza.com </option> 
 </select>

<input type="submit" value="Apply" name="exSubmit" class="button">


</form>
```