# How to get all the selected values of multiselect dropdown value in post/get?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with multiselect dropdown,on submit the values are passed through ajax by **Seralize** ,but only one value of multiselect dropdown is passed where i have selected more option on that dropdown.

```
var formdata= $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax(
{               
    url:base_url+"index.php/model/employee",  
    data: "employeedata="+employeeformdata,
    success: function(msg)
    { 
    //success message
    },                     
});
```

I have tried to get the values manually by `mval=$('#multi').val();` and appended it to url,since i am having a dynamic form i cant specify the id of multiselect dropdown and one form can have many multiselect dropdowns,Is there any method to pass the values on serialize/serializeArray ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.serialize()` method returns a string that looks like this:

```
selectNameA=valueA1&selectNameA=valueA2&selectNameB=valueB1
```

It is common to use the following when submitting a form via ajax with jQuery:

```
data: $("#form").serialize(),
```

Assuming you are using PHP on the server (since the question is tagged for PHP), you will want the value of the "name" attribute of the select element to end with "[]". (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407284/859640).)

```
<select name="xxx[]" ...
```

That way, `$_GET['xxx']` will be an array holding all the selected values.

Note: If you specify `type: 'post'` in your ajax call, you would use `$_POST` on the serveer, instead of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Not with serialize, and you might not have given values to your select options, but give this a try:

http://jsfiddle.net/94q7kcub/

dummycode

**jQuery:**

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
var multiselect = $('#marketplaces').val();
alert(multiselect);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="marketplaces">Marketplaces:</label>
    <select class="select2" multiple id="marketplaces">
        <option value="DE">Germany</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="FR">France</option>
        <option value="ES">Spain</option>
        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
<button id="clicker">click</button>
```