# Add several Tags to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

i made this form with a Tag Select Option and now i want to add all tags selected in the database:

form.php

```
<form action="actions/add_band.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" />
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Géneros</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="generos" data-placeholder="" class="chosen span6" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="" />
                <optgroup label="">
                  <option />Dallas Cowboys
                  <option />New York Giants
                  <option />Philadelphia Eagles
                  <option />Washington Redskins
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

add_band.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];


    $generos = $_POST['generos'];

    while (list(, $value) = each($generos)) {
        echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
    }

    foreach ($generos as $value) {
        echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
    }

    die();
}
```

Everytime i submit it gets me only the first tag selected.

How can i post all tags as an array or any other way easy to then Insert in the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of values from a mutliple select, you need to add square brackets to the name of it.

Change:

```
<select name="generos" data-placeholder="" class="chosen span6" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" style="width:100%;">
```

to

```
<select name="generos[]" data-placeholder="" class="chosen span6" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" style="width:100%;">
```