# Multiple select box values using jquery not getting saved in database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   function becomepartner()
   {

        var locations = []; 
    $('#geographicregion :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
        locations[i] = $(selected).val(); 

    });

        alert("locations ========"+locations);

    var partners = JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
        "lastName":$('#lname').val(),
        "geographicRegion":locations,


       });


       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: baseurl+"becomepartner/add",
           data: partners,
           dataType:"text",
           success:successmethod,
           error: function(data,status) {
            //alert("Error  "+status);
           }
       });

   }
```

HTML :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="becomepartnerfrm" style="padding:20px;" onsubmit="becomepartner(); return false;">

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="required-field-block">
                         <input id="fname" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('First Name should be in range of 3 to 20 characters(only alphabets are allowed')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" class="form-control input-md"  required="required">
                         <div class="required-icon">
                            <div class="text">*</div>
                         </div>
                        </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
                       <div class="required-field-block">
                       <input id="lname" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Last Name should be in range of 3 to 20 characters(only alphabets are allowed')"  onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"   class="form-control input-md" required="required">
                       <div class="required-icon">
                            <div class="text">*</div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Multiple -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="geolocation">Business Locations/Regions</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select id="geographicregion" name="geographicRegion" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="APAC">APAC</option>
    <option value="EMEA">EMEA</option>
    <option value="LATAM">LATAM</option>
    <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
    <option value="NA">NA</option>
    <option value="Public Sector">Public Sector</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>    
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Apply Now</button>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

In the above code i have multiple select box..i am selecing three values from it and getting it inside function..but only the last value is saving inside database instead of all the three values selected in the multiple select box..please throw some light on it??

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if we could see the server side code that's responsible for saving data to db

Comment: @MikeJM you can see my server side code..

Comment: please check your params on server and look if your select is within them

Comment: @Mephiztopheles no need to check anything i got my answer...thanks to all for your  support

Comment: @User2413 just keep your code simple, see my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can save all the values in database by the following code:

```
var geolocations=$('#geographicregion :selected').map(function(){return $(this).val(); }).get();
        var totalloc="";
        for(var i=0;i<geolocations.length;i++)
        {
            totalloc+=geolocations[i]+",";

        }   

        alert("locations ========"+locations);

    var partners = JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
        "lastName":$('#lname').val(),
        "geographicRegion":totalloc,


       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting multipal value needs to be Array in selection box

Change selection box name **geographicRegion[]**

Below is the process to get value on client side when form submit it help

```
<form onsubmit="functionname($this)"></form>
```

On Client side

```
function functionname($form)
{
    var values = {};
     $.each($form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
         values[field.name] = field.value;
     });
    alert(values.field_name);  
}
```

In Ajax use **async: false** property to transfer data.

Comment: can you please give me complete answer if possible??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php link for more reference

Comment: doesnt need to be an array. just need to handle it as an array on server

Answer (score 0):

just make it simple

```
var partners = JSON.stringify({
    "firstName": $('#fname').val(),
    "lastName":$('#lname').val(),
    "geographicRegion": $('#geographicregion').val()
});
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
           var geographicregion = $('#geographicregion').val().join();
           var partners = {
                "firstName": 'qwewqe',
                "lastName":'qwerewrwqe',
                "geographicRegion": geographicregion,
            };
```

Comment: the above code saves only one value inside database though we select two or three  values in multiple select box...

Comment: you can alert geographicregion value, it will give you all selected value

Comment: yes i know though it gives all the values in alert,it will save only last select value in database..if we want all the values to be saved in database..my approach is perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66911/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-user2413).

Comment: @User2413 check the edit code, if it doesn't work than use your one