# How to check options are selected or not?

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_POST["marketing"])){ 
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   if(strlen($value)<1)
    continue;
    echo "<option value='".$value."' selected >".$value."</option>";        
}
```

[image]

I have create dynamic options in php. All option are selected by default . I want to add all selected option into database.
How can i check options is selected or not?

Comment: "All option are selected by default " - what?

Comment: In foreach should be `$_POST['marketing']` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: remove the selected there... and create a new option above that. somewhat like this `<option selected>SELECT</option>`

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: User can select or deselect options. And multiple option can be selected.

Comment: @BurningCrystals: probably `select` with multiple `attribute`.

Comment: I think what you looking for is explained in this post

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, we do not know what else is being posted through your form though..

```
if (isset($_POST["marketing"])){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
        $iselected = ($value == $_POST['marketing']) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $value . "' $iselected>" . $value . "</option>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @moffeltje Why? There is no indication key `marketing` holds an array value