# How to assign HTML form multiple selected options to PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have HTML form with multiple select element to let the users select multiple options from the list for submission. The form method is `POST` and it posts the form to PHP file. I figured it out how to `echo` multiple selected options through out reading this [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php) but I am unable to write those values to a variable as string, and having space between each option-value. Is it possible to achieve this without using array?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="place[]" id="place" multiple>
    <optgroup label="Ottawa">
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
        <option value="Windsor">Windsor</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Alberta">
        <option value="Brooks">Brooks</option>
        <option value="Calgary">Calgary</option>
        <option value="Cold Lake">Cold Lake</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET['place'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
?>
```

The above code only `echo` the values but not assigning it to variable as string. Can I simply use `$locations =` instead of `echo`?

*Note: There are many **Questions and Answers** that shows how to assign select option value to PHP variable but not for multiple option.*

Comment: If "The form method is POST and it posts the form to PHP file" then why are you using `$_GET['place'] `? And since you want to convert an array into a string, why aren't you just using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

Comment: @j08691 I have no problem using `implode()` as I am new to PHP and struggling with methods. What will be the correct statement in that case?

Comment: `$locations = implode(' ', $_POST['place'])`

Comment: @j08691 Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you were using a post request, `$_GET['place']` won't work. So using `$_POST['place']` instead, you can glue the values of the array together using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$locations = implode(' ', $_POST['place']);
```