# HTML multiple select dropdown not returning multiple values in php,returnong only the last value instead of multiple

Tags: php, html

I have a multiple select dropdown field in html which has to return multiple values but it is returning only single value.

```
 <select name="select[]"  multiple>
 <OPTGROUP label="cars">
 <option value="car1">car1</option>
 <option value="car2">car2</option>
 <option value="car3">car3</option>
 </OPTGROUP>
 <OPTGROUP label="bikes">
 <option value="bike1">bike1</option>
 <option value="bike2">bike2</option>
 <option value="bike3">bike3</option>
```

Below is the PHP to return the multiple values that are selected:

```
 $select = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['select']);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the contents of `_POST['select']`?

Comment: remove [] from html tag, if there is only one select tag

Comment: Check this link for more help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: `$_POST['select']` is an array. You can't do `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on an array, as it expects param 2 to be a string. You need to loop over each value to do escape, without overwriting the previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok. 
Write select tag as below:-

```
<select name="select[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Now print it:-

```
    if(isset($_POST['select'])){
        $selected = $_POST['select']; 
        // Here $selected is an array. So need a foreach loop            
        foreach ($selected as $option)
        {
             print "You are selected $option<br/>";
             //print mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $option);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i use print or echo am able to get all the vlaues but when i assign mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $option); to $example to insert in db i am getting only one value.

Comment: You're welcome :) You need an array to store all $option.  Try this code :- $data[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $option); and print_r($data) at end.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['select'])){
        $selected = $_POST['select']; 
        // Here $selected is an array. So need a foreach loop            
        foreach ($selected as $option)
        {
            $data[] =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $option);
        }
    }                  i have inserted this part of code but when iam inserting $data into the db column am not getting all the values.Please help in this

Comment: You cannot store array in DB. So you need to use implode method. Write $result = implode(',',$data); Now store $result in DB

Answer (score 0):

there is two things you have to do one first check your form method if it is not POST then you can't call it like $_POST you have to use $_GET or $_REQUEST and change select[] to select

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select[]" multiple="multiple">
```

you can check it by

```
print_r($_POST['select']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select[]" multiple="multiple">
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $selected = $_POST['select'];
    $select = implode(",",$selected);
}
```

use implode method, to insert $select values in database ....