# PHP preg_match_all in option value without disabled options

Tags: php

Any suggestion how to do the result value option without disabled option with php preg_match_all?

```
<option value="1" disabled="disabled"> google</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">- yahoo</option>
<option value="3">- youtube</option>
<option value="4">- facebook</option>
<option value="5" disabled="disabled"> twitter</option>
<option value="6">- tumblr</option>
<option value="7">- bing</option>
```

how to echo just value without disabled options maybe with preg_match_all?

i have some code but not work,

```
   $string = array(
   '/<option value=\"(.*)\" selected=\"selected\">-/sU',
   '/<option value=\"(.*)\">-/U',);

$option = curl_exec($ch);
foreach ($string as $key) {
 if (preg_match_all($key, $option, $matches)) {
  $count = count($matches[1]);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
     echo $matches[1][$i]."\n";
  }
 }else {
   echo "match NOT found";
 }
}
```

i want to the result like this,

```
value = 2,3,4,6,7
```

thanks for helping,

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Comment: You could go the other way around. You know the options, put them in an array, grab the disabled ones and subtract them from the array with options.

Comment: i update my question and insert my php code, but there not working, how about that?

Comment: You should use XPath. If you want I can show you how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath is easy, check the following solution:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<option value="1" disabled="disabled"> google</option><option value="2" selected="selected">- yahoo</option><option value="3">- youtube</option><option value="4">- facebook</option><option value="5" disabled="disabled"> twitter</option><option value="6">- tumblr</option><option value="7">- bing</option>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$notDisabledOptions = $xpath->query("//option[not(@disabled)]");
$numberOfOptions = $notDisabledOptions->length;

for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfOptions; $i++){
      echo $notDisabledOptions->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->nodeValue;
}
```

For more info on how to use XPath, check this [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: thanks Boma, this code work fine,
the result is value select (google, yahoo, etc)
but i want to the result is value="xx" (the xx)
so the result like this:
2,3,4,6,7 not  yahoo- youtube- facebook- tumblr- bing

Comment: @jose Check the code now, It returns attribute value.

Comment: thanks for fast reply,
I got error with attribute value:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNamedNodeMap as array on line 12

Comment: It's working fine here, i guess you have older version of php, try now, this should work

Comment: wow, thanks Borna, now its work fine, thanks for the help Borna

Comment: no problem :) just vote as accepted answer please. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can set the option values in the array. And then manipulate that array according to your likings.

Check this answer out, this might be of the same answer to your question.

[How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

You put your < options > in a < select > tag, and then identify a name  < select name="name" > and retrieve your selected options by referencing the select name tag.

Please let me know if it helped, or didnt.