# How can I get the values of a multiselect into an echo statement?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, select

I am trying to get the values of a multiselect to be listed into a php email form. The variable is name="variable[] "

I don't know how to go about it, so any advice would be awesome

```
  $message = "<html><head><title></title></head>
        <body>
            <p>Sentence".$_POST['somevarriable']."</p>
            <p>Another Sentence". [I want to put an array here]."</p>
        </body>
        </html>";
```

Comment: you could use `implode(',', $_POST['variable'])`

Comment: awesome, that worked!

Comment: `[]` makes PHP create an array of those values, therefore you need to convert that array-of-values into a string for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (Untested)

```
$message = "
    <html>
        <head><title></title></head>
        <body>
            <p>Sentence" .$_POST['somevarriable']. "</p>
            <p>Another Sentence "
    ;

    foreach ($_POST['variable'] as $selectedOption){
        $message .= $selectedOption . ' ';
    }

    $message .= "
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

Reference:

[How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Comment: Ya, the implode thing worked perfectly. But ya this is exactly what I was looking for. :)