# php how to combine with comma separation the $_GET variable same name multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am submitting the form and getting the url like `http://localhost/web/test.php?cuisine=1&cuisine=2&cuisine=3`.

I want to get the result like `echo $_GET['cuisine'];` and the output should be `"1,2,3" / $rt = "1,2,3";` i want to use it in query `(select * from table where id in ($rt) )`

My Form:
    
    
    No Cuisine Restriction

```
$result = $db->query("
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cuisines
WHERE
    status=1
order by id
");
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["ename"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

</form>
```

I have tried the below but it is taking only the last id#3, when i select only the one not multiple it works fine:

```
$temp = $_GET['cuisine'];
$thelist    =   implode(",",$temp);
```

I have tried `http://localhost/web/test.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3` & printing the result it gives me this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )` but how to use it in  `WHERE id IN (....);` i tried bu can not.

Comment: Ids have to be unique. Try `id[]=`, then iterate over the `$_GET['id']`, it will be an array

Comment: If you do `?var=foo&var=bar&var=baz` then `var` is equal to `baz` because that's its last assignment. `var[]=foo&var[]=bar` on the other hand..

Comment: You may need to change your html select statement so that it has brackets following the name, e.g.  <select name ="cuisine[]"...   see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

Comment: You can change your select name as array like cuisine[] and use explode( ',',$_GET['cuisine']) and pass this to IN  query operator.

Comment: Works for me.. update your question to what you tried. http://chrisisdoingwhat.com/sample.php?id[]=1&id[]=2 `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Update the question to your usage.

Comment: Which form element in the form above has the name: `id`?  I only see `cuisine`.

Comment: @chris85 updated the question...

Comment: You need to `implode` the array, then it will be a string. You also are opening yourself up to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by chris85 and Craig.  Change the name of your select field to `cuisine[]`.

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
<form action="">
    <select name="cuisine[]" multiple>
        <option value="">None</option>
        <?php $cuisines = ['indian', 'english', 'thai', 'italian']; ?>
        <?php foreach($cuisines as $key => $cuisine) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $cuisine; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I select 'english' and 'thai', output reads:

```
array (size=1)
  'cuisine' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: Side note: I don't think that multiple selects are that user friendly.  Perhaps consider using check boxes.