# Dropdown added to html field but output can not be seen in db

Tags: php, html

According to requirements, I have added dropdown box in a field of my html form.As soon as I submit the form, all information is added to my db in phpmyadmin except that dropdown field.
An error is displayed as:

"Notice: Undefined index: Country in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 13"

And information is saved in my db.
"Information Added"

```
<div class="container13">
    <button type="submit"><a href="emsolutions.co.in" target="_blank">Submit</button></a>
</div>
<div class="container13">
    <button type="submit"><a href="emsolutions.co.in" target="_blank">Submit</button></a>
</div>
```

But I want it to submit with all entries.

Comment: Please also post the PHP Script and or SQL statement.

Comment: Please post the HTML form, is possible you are missing a name attribute in your `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write muliple selection form a dropdown to a single db field.

If you have muliple values selected Country will be an array in PHP: 
[How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Comment: I would suggest you to use **Include** and **Exclude** functions to store and retrieve it in one field.