# Value of Multiple select input text field in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How can I get the value of a multiple select input field in CodeIgniter controller?

[I want a multiple select input field shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oebi.png)

I have added below html code.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple  multiple_selection form-control" name="student[]" multiple="multiple"  >
                <option value="1">Student1</option>
                <option value="2">Student2</option>
                <option value="3">Student3</option>
                <option value="4">Student4</option>
                <option value="5">Student5</option>
                <option value="6">Student6</option>
              </select>
```

I am using given code to fetch the value of this input field. But I didn't get the value.

```
$studentname = array();
    $studentname =$this->input->post('student[]');
    echo 'studentName:'.$studentname;
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Your values will be posted in an array:

```
$studentNames = $this->input->post('student');
```

You can then access each value using loop:

```
foreach($studentNames as $name){
    echo "Student name is $name";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method. I didn't get it. So I posted this question.

Comment: The trick is, that you use the name attribute `student[]` like in your code example and use it woithout the brackets in your code  when retrieving it, like shown by Kisaragi.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use [] while you are echoing post value, you already define in name='student[]';

```
 $studentname =$this->input->post('student');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($studentname);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

for naming sake make it student students since its a multislect

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple  multiple_selection form-control" name="students[]" multiple="multiple"  >
    <option value="1">Student1</option>
    <option value="2">Student2</option>
    <option value="3">Student3</option>
    <option value="4">Student4</option>
    <option value="5">Student5</option>
    <option value="6">Student6</option>
 </select>
```

in controller:

```
//get the post values of students (if you dump the post you will see that $_POST['students'] is an array
$students = $this->input->post('students');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

```
//will contain the values of the selected students ex. var_dump($students) will produce [1,2,4];

//you will need to loop over students since it is an array

foreach($students as $id){
  echo "Student id is {$id}";
}
```