# Image picker(multiple images) php

Tags: php, html

I am using [Image Picker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) to select multiple `options`.

> Image Picker is a simple jQuery plugin that transforms a select
>   element into a more user-friendly graphical interface.

I want to retrieve the selected `options` and print them after submitting them via a `form`.

---

**HTML CODE**(again I am using Image Picker)

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="visualstyle[]" class="image-picker" id="visualstyle">
                                <option data-img-src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" value="1">1</option>
                                <option data-img-src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" value="2">2</option>
                                <option data-img-src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" value="3">3</option>
                                <option data-img-src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

This is inside a form `<form action="form.php" method="post">`

**PHP** (form.php)

```
<?php
$values = $_POST['visualstyle'];

foreach ($values as $a){
    echo $a;
}
?>
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php) but it doesn't work. Only a blank page appears when I submit the form after selecting multiple options.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['visualstyle']);` give?

Comment: I realised my mistake. I was not running the HTML file via the server and that's why it didn't work. Thanks anyway :)...